# Ways to represent pattern in various languages

Tags: c++, pattern-matching

I have some C++ code. I'm duplicating a pattern repeatedly in it which isn't pleasant.

```
class layerclass {
public:
  vector<int> a;
  vector<int> b;
  vector<int> c;

  bool isInA(int x) { return a.find(x) != a.end(); } // true if x is in a
  bool isInB ...
  bool isInC ...
};
class innerlayer : public layerclass {
public:
  layerclass *outerlayer;
  bool isInA(int x) {
    if (layerclass::isInA(x)) return true;
    return outerlayer->isInA(x);
  }
  bool isInB(int x) ...  // these two fn's will be identical to isInA()
  bool isInC(int x) ...  // with the exception of calling isInB/C()
};
```

In my case there really are only about 3 containers to search this way, but it's very bothersome for me to see. A solution might be to tag-dispatch somehow:

```
class layerclass {
public:
  vector<int> a;
  vector<int> b;
  vector<int> c;
  enum class members { a, b, c };

  bool isIn(int x, members m) { 
    switch (m) {
      case members::a: return a.find(x) != a.end(); 
    ...
  }

};
class innerlayer : public layerclass {
public:
  layerclass *outerlayer;
  bool isIn(int x, member m) {
     if (layerclass::isIn(x, m) return true;
     return outerlayer->isIn(x, m);
  }
};
```

Ok that's a little better but I still have the duplicated code in layerclass::isIn() and have to maintain the enum. Is this the best I cand do in C++? Do other languages offer a convenient solution to this outside of something like a preprocessor macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the class as follows, so there is no duplicate code in `isIn`

```
class layerclass {
public:
    vector<int> a;
    vector<int> b;
    vector<int> c;
    bool isIn(vector<int> &vec, int x) { return vec.find(x) != a.end(); }
    bool isInA(int x) { return isIn(a, x); }
    bool isInB(int x) { return isIn(b, x); }
    bool isInC(int x) { return isIn(c, x); }
};
```